Scraping fund meta data in Yahoo Finance (not prices)
Yahoo finance changed their website structure. The following R code worked previously to scrape fund meta data. The code no longer works to scrape target variables (PE, NAV, Beta, Yield, etc). The bug in the code is the node_txt variable. It references a 'table' that is no longer there. I'm not an expert at inspecting page source to find where the list data is stored. Any help on updating the code is appreciated.
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

ticker <- "IVV"
url <- paste0("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",ticker)

ivv_html <- read_html(url)

node_txt <- ".svelte-tx3nkj" # This contains "table" info of interest

df <- ivv_html %>% 
  html_nodes(paste0(".container", node_txt)) %>%
  map_dfr(~{
    tibble(
      label = html_nodes(.x, paste0(".label", node_txt)) %>% 
        html_text(trim = TRUE),
      value = html_nodes(.x, paste0(".value", node_txt)) %>% 
        html_text(trim = TRUE)
    )
  })

df %>% 
  filter(label %in% c("NAV", "PE Ratio (TTM)", "Yield", "Beta (5Y Monthly)", "Expense Ratio (net)"))


You should not keep deleting and reposting the same question. Since this code doesn't work, it's unclear what exactly the desired output is here. Yahoo has the right to change their site every day if they want. It doesn't make sense to answer questions about specific sites if you are not willing to put in the effort to understand how the code words and what you need to do to keep it up to date. It's always better to use public APIs rather than trying to scrape HTML if possible.

LOL..the site requested that I delete the question and they provided input to improve the question. Webscaping HTML is sometimes the only way to get the data needed. The question is valid and the requested output is defined by the last line. The named variables are the meta data in the first table on the URL. Kindly provide an answer (if you have one)

From a quick look at that page, you could try replacing svelte with yf.

Search for yf-tx3nkj in the li class attribute extracting the text within span and reform into a matrix.
library(xml2)

ivv_html |>
  xml_find_all("//li[contains(@class, 'yf-tx3nkj')]/span/text()") |>
  as.character() |>
  tail(12) |>
  matrix(6, 2, byrow = TRUE)

##      [,1]                     [,2]    
## [1,] "NAV"                    "561.61"
## [2,] "PE Ratio (TTM)"         "28.29" 
## [3,] "Yield"                  "1.30%" 
## [4,] "YTD Daily Total Return" "18.34%"
## [5,] "Beta (5Y Monthly)"      "1.00"  
## [6,] "Expense Ratio (net)"    "0.03%" 


Well done. Thank you
